# Unity vs Unreal Engine

Tags: unity

I am beginner in VR development.

Which game engine is better between Unity and Unreal Engine?

I am thinking to pick Unreal Engine as it has better graphics.

Do you think in the future, Unity will have better graphics than Unreal Engine?

Thank you.

Comment: Opinion based questions are off topic. The graphics are as good as you have assets. If you you have to decide between those two, pick the one which language you know better

Answer (score -1):

Game engines don't have "better" or "worse" graphics, the graphics depend on which rendering software you are using and how good of an artist you are.

**Unity vs  Unreal**

Unity is advertised to everyone, Unreal engine is advertised to professional artists and clueless beginners.

So if you have no skills you will find more tutorials for unity because more people use it, but you will also have to learn more stuff.

If you are an artist but not a programmer, you can make decent games with unreal without thouching much code, at most you'll just copy and paste free or stolen code you find on the internet when blueprints don't get you there.

and if you have no skills at all but got a big bank for  a big computer and a lot of assets that you can buy from the market, unreal is made especially for you.

That's why Unreal Engine got kind of an infamy for being used by a lot of talentless scammers, especially on kickstarter.com because people using it either already are professionals making big games or are completely clueless dreamers/scammers trying o resell you free assets or stuff they got from the unreal engine market and call their game "the new big thing"

Comment: This is a mix of good advice (game engines don't inherently have better or worse graphics), and nonsense (Unreal seems more realistic because it uses DirectX - no, DirectX is just a dialect for talking to the graphics card. It does not change the level of realism you can achieve vs other APIs of similar generation like Vulkan or Metal). Devices do not "have different renderers pre-installed" - the renderer is part of the game/engine software. What devices have is different GPUs and video memory, which places constraints on what your renderer software can do with them.

Comment: The section added on Unity vs Unreal reads as unsubstantiated opinion, and honestly a bit of a rant, not backed up by facts. Questions asking to compare/choose a game engine are officially not on-topic for this site, because they tend to attract heavily opinion-based answers like this. (See the close notice at the top of this page)

Comment: @DMGregory the internet is filled with blogs and videos saying things along the lines of : "making scam games/kickstarters has never been easier with unreal 5" but you won't find anything saying the same thing about unity. hours uppon hours of contenct explaining how easy it is for any noob to make a cinematic trailer for games that are never gonna be released just to scam people. Look into all the drama from the last 4-5 years, pretty much every single gamedev scam was related to unreal engine, not to unity. It's not an opinion it's just recent history... and present too, cause it continues.